# Modifying labels on some enumerated items

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

In an `enumerate` environment, I want a few (not all) of the items to have asterisks which appear *before* the number (I don't feel strongly about whether the number or the asterisk is horizontally aligned with the other numbers).  Is there a less crufty way to do this than, say, using multiple lists (or — horrors — numbering manually)?

I'm already using `enumitem` for an unrelated purpose, if that helps, although I didn't find a solution after a quick skim of its manual.

Comment: Is the number of asterisks variable or is it always the same number independently of the item number?

Comment: Always the same and always one; sorry, I wasn't very clear.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

How about this

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\myitem}{\refstepcounter{enumi}\item[$*$\theenumi.]}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
 \myitem first 
 \item second
 \item third
 \myitem fourth
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is relevant, but this way the `*` will not be part of a reference to the item.

Comment: Fortunately I don't need to make any references to the list items.

Comment: I'm accepting this right away partly because I'm amused at how well it confirmed my feeling that there may be a really easy solution which I could find more quickly using this site than thinking about it myself.  Nevertheless, I'd be interested to see others.

Comment: @cmhughes -- the asterisk might show up a bit more prominently if the digits were aligned.  for that, just add the (default) period after `\theenumi`: `\newcommand{\myitem}{\stepcounter{enumi}\item[$*$\theenumi.]}`

Comment: @barbarabeeton good idea, thanks- see edit

Comment: Neat! I made this: ``\newcommand{\correct}{\refstepcounter{enumi}\item[\mbox{\color{red}{\ding{52}}\hspace{1ex}}\theenumi.]}``, which requires the ``pifont`` and ``xcolor`` packages.

Answer (score 27):

Redefine momentarily `\labelenumi` (it's a bit more difficult if you want it for any nesting level). It works also with `\label`, but the asterisk won't be part of the reference.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\asteriskitem{*\,}
\def\sitem{%
  \let\originallabelenumi\labelenumi
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\labelenumi\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\asteriskitem\labelenumi}%
  \item
  \let\labelenumi\originallabelenumi
}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item a
\sitem b
\item c
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for the record, here is something that should work with every nesting level:

```
\makeatletter
\def\sitem{%
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\originallabel\csname labelenum\romannumeral\@enumdepth\endcsname
  \expandafter\def\csname labelenum\romannumeral\@enumdepth\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\asteriskitem\originallabel}%
  \item
  \expandafter\let\csname labelenum\romannumeral\@enumdepth\endcsname\originallabel
}
\makeatother
```

### Explanation

Let's see how the simpler solution works. To begin with, we have to know that `\item` uses `\labelenumi` for typesetting the first level numbers, and that it is a parameterless macro.

We want to change the meaning of `\labelenumi` so that it typesets also the asterisk, so we define a macro for the asterisk and a small space; then we define a command `\sitem` that changes the definition, issues `\item` and restores the original `\labelenumi`. The "easy" method for doing this, that is, changing the definition in a group, doesn't unfortunately work. So we save the original meaning in `\originallabelenumi` and do

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\labelenumi\expandafter{%
  \expandafter\asteriskitem\labelenumi}%
```

The first `\expandafter` activates all the following ones, so that the expansion of `\labelenumi` is obtained *before* `\def` acts (the fact that `\labelenumi` has no arguments is very important here).

The general solution is very similar, but requires knowing something more about `enumerate`. The nesting level is accessible through the value of `\@enumdepth`, which is a "TeX counter"; with `\romannumeral\@enumdepth` we can thus refer to the right LaTeX macro `\labelenumi`, `\labelenumii`, `\labelenumiii` or `\labelenumiv` with `\csname labelenum\romannumeral\@enumdepth\endcsname`.

Therefore we save the meaning of the right macro with

```
\expandafter\let\expandafter\originallabel\csname labelenum\romannumeral\@enumdepth\endcsname
```

With `etoolbox` this might become

```
\letcs\originallabel{labelenum\romannumeral\@enumdepth}
```

Getting the expansion of `\originallabel` is done essentially as before:

```
\expandafter\def\csname labelenum\romannumeral\@enumdepth\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{%
  \expandafter\asteriskitem\originallabel}
```

but using a slick trick. The first `\expandafter` triggers `\csname`, which expands everything it finds up to the matching `\endcsname`, including the inner `\expandafter` which triggers the following ones. Finally the right token (say `\labelenumi` if the value of `\@enumdepth` is 1) is put after `\def` and TeX would see the correct command among

```
\def\labelenumi{\asterisk<expansion of \originallabel>}
\def\labelenumii{\asterisk<expansion of \originallabel>}
\def\labelenumiii{\asterisk<expansion of \originallabel>}
\def\labelenumiv{\asterisk<expansion of \originallabel>}
```

according to the value of `\@enumdepth`, as desired. After issuing `\item`, the meaning of `\labelenum??` is restored.

Comment: +1 wonderful answer! I plan to study it in the hope of gaining a better understanding of `\expandafter`

Comment: @cmhughes I've added some explanations.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a much simpler approach.

Borrowing (heavily) from this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/287359/70067), define a command (`\difficult`) that will put the asterisk in place:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\difficult}{%
  \leavevmode\makebox[0pt][r]{\large$\ast$\hspace{1.5em}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item a 
\item \difficult b 
\item c
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that this will behave well with `\label` (the asterisk will not appear however).

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own `item`. In the following example I used `\bulletitem`.

To take care of nested environments you can do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\bulletitem{%
  \edef\@tempctr{\csname c@enum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth\endcsname}%
  \expandafter\advance\csname c@enum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth\endcsname by 1%
  \item[$\bullet$(\the\@tempctr)]}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item item no.1
\item item no.2
\bulletitem No.3
\item item no.4
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following updates `\item` to work with either `\item*` or `\item[..]` (the former being new and the latter being the default):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\olditem\item
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\item}{\@ifstar\@sitem\olditem}
\newcommand{\@sitem}{%
  \refstepcounter{\@enumctr}%
  \olditem[\textbullet~\csname label\@enumctr\endcsname]}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item item no.1
  \item item no.2
  \item[$\bullet$~3.] item no.3
  \item item no.4
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item item no.1
  \item item no.2
  \item* item no.3
  \item item no.4
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```