# Insert a symbol before the item

Tags: lists, enumerate

I'm preparing a guide for my students and I want to put a symbol before the item’s symbol in the enumeration of the exercises for indicate that this exercise is more difficult, very similar that the math's books.

For example:

1. blah
2. blah

(*)3. blah

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Does [Modifying labels on some enumerated items](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52715/) help?

Comment: Just use `\item[(*)3]`.

Comment: Please wait for a reaction of op before closing this question. Must this question be closed one hour after asking?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
Easy
\item 
Easy
\item [(*)\stepcounter{enumi}\arabic{enumi}.]
Hard
\item
Easy
\end{enumerate}
```

You will probably want to use an optional argument of `\item` as a short definition, e.g.

```
\def\Hitem{\item [(*)\stepcounter{enumi}\arabic{enumi}.]} % Hard item.
```