# different labels for enumerate environment?

Tags: lists, enumerate

How can I use enumerate environment to generate something like this:

1) some text

2*) some text

3) some text

Comment: have you seen [Modifying labels on some enumerated items](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52715)

Comment: yes, it was very useful.