# How to change the label of one item in an enumitem list

Tags: lists, enumitem

I want to change the label of one item in a list. I am using the `enumitem` package, I am very fond of it, and I have to keep using it (lots of other code would break).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[]{enumitem}

\begin{document}
Foobar

\begin{enumerate}[label={(\arabic*)}]
        \item baz
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[resume,label={(*\arabic*)}]
        \item xyzzy
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[resume,label={(\arabic*)}]
        \item quux
\end{enumerate}

Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

The result is a list

```
 (1) baz
(*2) xyzzy
 (3) quux
```

However, I would like to do something like

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[]{enumitem}

\begin{document}
Foobar

\begin{enumerate}[label={(\arabic*)}]
        \item baz
        \staritem xyzzy
        \item quux
\end{enumerate}

Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

It would be very cool if the `enumitem` package would make code like `\item[label=(*\arabic*)]` possible. But as far as I know, an easy solution is not available.

What would you do? Please define a command `\staritem` in your answer, as this would be a more orthogonal solution than hacking it straight into the document text. Alternatively, hacking `\item` to accept options (as in `\item[label=(*\arabic*)]`) would be awesome!

Comment: related (but not with the specific requirement for `enumitem`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52715/modifying-labels-on-some-enumerated-items

Comment: @egreg — Awesome. Somehow it did not pop up out of my search. Your answer there is fabulous.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Put the asterisk in the specification of the label:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\staritem}{\global\asterisktrue\item}
\newcommand{\perhapsasterisk}{%
  \ifasterisk*\global\asteriskfalse\fi
}
\newif\ifasterisk

\begin{document}
Foobar

\begin{enumerate}[label={(\protect\perhapsasterisk\arabic*)}]
\item baz
\staritem xyzzy
\item quux
\staritem xxx
\end{enumerate}

Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful answer, because (i) this easily generalises to nested lists, and (ii) changing the format of labels now only needs to happen in one place.

Answer (score 26):

I am not sure whether this is, what you want to achieve, but you can explicitly set the label of an item.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}
Foobar

\begin{enumerate}[label={(\arabic*)}]
        \item baz
        \item[\refstepcounter{enumi}(*\number\value{enumi})] xyzzy
        \item quux
\end{enumerate}

Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

I suppose, the `\refstepcounter` statement inside the `[]` is necessary because the counter is not advanced if one sets the label by hand.

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks. In the end it was easier than I thought. I don't know why I didn't try this combo. (I was trying to difficult stuff, somewhere in the internals of `enumitem`.) Note that you have one `*` too much. In the end I did `\def\staritem{\refstepcounter{enumi}\item[(*\number\value{enumi})]}`. Would you mind to edit this into your answer?

Comment: @jmc: Regarding that extra *****: I thought you intended to so do, see your middle example in your MWE.

Comment: The example only has a `*` in front of the digit. In the code it reads `*\arabic*`, but the latter `*` is part of the `enumitem` syntax.

Comment: @jmc: Ok, I admit: I have never used `enumitem` before ;-) I changed as you wished