# How to modify labels on some (not all) etaremune items

Tags: enumerate, etaremune

Similar to this question [about enumerated items](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52715/modifying-labels-on-some-enumerated-items?answertab=active#tab-top), how to do the same thing for the etaremune items?

Say, the default 'etaremune' output is:

4. fourth
5. third (I mean '3', not '5')
6. second (I mean '2')
7. first (I mean '1'). Somehow the formatting makes it '4.5.6.7'...

I am trying to add a 'star' in front of some (not all) of the entries (automatic item-counting), i.e.,

4. fourth

*3. third

2. second

*1. first

I have tried with the method given in the example of the `enumerate` environment, but the item-counting seems not working well.

Comment: Can you add some example code indicating what you're trying to do?

Comment: @ArunDebray, thanks for your kind attention. I just updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways -- unfortunately the `enumitem` package still does not support reversed `enumerate` lists, otherwise, this `starred` item would be very easy then with `enumitem`.

The first one checks whether the `enumi` counter has an odd value and uses `\textasteriskcentered` then (Note: `odd`, since the counter has not been increased at the stage of evaluation)

The other way uses a conditional `\ifstarreditem` and use it `{\starreditemtrue \item foo}` within a `{...}` pair, in order to limit the range of the setting of `\starreditemtrue`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etaremune}


\let\origlabelenumi\labelenumi % For latter purposes

\newif\ifstarreditem

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\bfseries\ifodd\value{enumi}\textasteriskcentered\fi\theenumi.}

\begin{etaremune}
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\item Four
\end{etaremune}

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\bfseries\ifstarreditem\textasteriskcentered\fi\theenumi.}

\starreditemfalse
\begin{etaremune}
\item One 
{\starreditemtrue \item Two}
\item Three
\item Four
\end{etaremune}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much @Christian! This just works great! The if-condition way inside the {...} pair is quite nice!