# Adding a star in the tasks package

Tags: tasks

I am using the `tasks` package to create a list of maths problems in a textbook. Usually, these textbooks use a star or asterisk symbol to point out questions which are a bit more challenging than the rest; like this:
[image: With star]

How can I go about this? Here's my code, which renders the star after the 'e)', but I want it before as shown above.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,tasks,geometry}
\newcommand{\difficult}{\large$\star$\normalsize~~}
\geometry{a4paper, portrait, margin=1in}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Prove the following statements by induction.
        \begin{tasks}(2)
            \task $\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^n r^5=\frac{n^2}{12}(n+1)^2(2n^2+2n-1)$
            \task $\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{r(r+1)}=\frac{r}{r+1}$
            \task $\displaystyle\prod_{r=1}^n r^{12}=(r!)^{12}$ 
            \task $\displaystyle\prod_{r=2}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{r^2}\right)=\frac{n+1}{2n};~~\forall n\geq 2$
            \task \difficult $\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^n rx^{r-1}=\frac{1-(n-1)x^n+nx^{n+1}}{(x-1)^2}$   
            \task $\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{r^2+r+1}{r(r+1)}=\frac{n(n+2)}{n+1}$     
        \end{tasks}     
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since one necessarily have to indicate which is different from the rest, you might just as well move the `\star` into position manually via `\difficult` rather than trying to automate things.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tasks,geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, portrait, margin=1in}

\newcommand{\difficult}{%
  \leavevmode\makebox[0pt][r]{\large$\star$\hspace{1.5em}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Prove the following statements by induction.
  \begin{tasks}(2)
    \task $\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^n r^5=\frac{n^2}{12}(n+1)^2(2n^2+2n-1)$
    \task\difficult $\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{r(r+1)} = \frac{r}{r+1}$
    \task $\displaystyle\prod_{r=1}^n r^{12}=(r!)^{12}$ 
    \task $\displaystyle\prod_{r=2}^n \biggl( 1-\frac{1}{r^2} \biggr) = \frac{n+1}{2n};~~\forall n\geq 2$
    \task\difficult $\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^n rx^{r-1} = \frac{1-(n-1)x^n+nx^{n+1}}{(x-1)^2}$
    \task $\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{r^2+r+1}{r(r+1)} = \frac{n(n+2)}{n+1}$
  \end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```