# Mark a question with an asterisk in enumeration mode

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

I am using the `\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}` package for automatic enumeration of question in my LaTeX document. However, I would like sometimes to mark (a) question(s) with an asterisk as to declare its level of difficulty. How can I do that?

I certainly don't like doing it manually , e.g after the `\item` command to place an asterisk like so `\item $*$`. Also I would like the asterisk to be a superscript to the number e.g something like `5*` suppose.

Sample:

```
1. This is a sample question.
2. This is another sample question.
3*. This is a sample question with some difficulty.
```

This is what I would like the output to be. However the dot. I would like to be aligned with the other dots, if that , is of course possible.

Can this be done?

Comment: I think this has already been asked before, see for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52715/modifying-labels-on-some-enumerated-items and change `$*$\theenumi.` to `\theenumi\up{*}.`

Comment: Thanks @DamienDtx. I used your comment to answer my question. Feel free to vote to close it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As answered by Damien Dtx , the solution to my question is the macro:

```
\newcommand{\myitem}{\refstepcounter{enumi}\item[\theenumi\up{*}.]}
```

This works!

**Edit:** I had mistyped it.

Comment: I had to make a sligh modification to the code. In the label of enumi I am using "label=\textbf{\arabic*}." so that "." in the macro is unnecessary for me. So , I removed it.