# Enumerated list with repeated numbers with an asterisk

Tags: lists, enumerate, itemize, document-classes

I'm trying to obtain:

```
1. text text text
2. text text text
2*. text text text
3. text text text
4. text text text
4*. text text text
```

I've seen something similar done with:

```
\newcommand{\myitem}{\refstepcounter{enumi}\item[\theenumi\up{*}.]}
```

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298888/mark-a-question-with-an-asterisk-in-enumeration-mode)
. However, it is not what I'm trying to accomplish.

**EDIT. My God, you people are awesome!!!** If I could only get as many responses in the Cross Validated stack I would finish my thesis in a week;)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you plan to use `\label` and `\ref` for such modified items?

Comment: No, just need a fancy looking list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

It is better to let the very right of labels aligned together. Define `\newcommand{\myitem}{\item[$\vphantom{x}^{*}$\theenumi]}` and use `\setlist[enumerate,1]{leftmargin=*, label=\arabic*.}` in the preamble.

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\myitem}{\item[$\vphantom{x}^{*}$\theenumi]}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{leftmargin=*, label=\arabic*.}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \myitem Item 2 (with asterisk)
    \item Item 3
    \item Item 4
    \item Item 5
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

A “simple” modification for a first level list with the default `1.` appearance of labels:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\repitem}{%
  \addtocounter{enumi}{-1}%
  \let\savedtheenumi\theenumi
  \renewcommand{\theenumi}{\arabic{enumi}\itemasterisk}%
  \item\let\theenumi\savedtheenumi
}
\protected\def\itemasterisk{\rlap{*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item One
\item Two
\repitem Two*
\item Three
\item Four
\repitem Four*

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{fancyenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[fancyenumerate]{label=\arabic*\perhapsasterisk.}
\protected\def\perhapsasterisk{}
\protected\def\itemasterisk{\rlap{*}}

\newcommand{\repitem}{%
  \addtocounter{fancyenumeratei}{-1}%
  \let\perhapsasterisk\itemasterisk
  \item\def\perhapsasterisk{}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{fancyenumerate}

\item One
\item Two
\repitem Two*
\item Three
\item Four
\repitem Four*

\end{fancyenumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The number is repeated by I'm note getting the asterisk. Maybe because I use the enumitem package. I don't know

Comment: @DexzMen Don't hide important details.

Comment: I'm sorry. Just trying to finish my thesis. I'm a total noob;)

Comment: BTW. I came with the idea of enumitem just after Skillmon answer.

Comment: @DexzMen I added a solution for enumitem

Answer (score 1):

A small (referable) implementation doing what you're asking for:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand \myitem { o }
  {%
    \IfValueTF {#1}
      {%
        \item[#1]%
      }
      {%
        \addtocounter{enumi}{-1}%
        \let\theenumiBAK\theenumi
        \def\theenumi{\theenumiBAK\myitem@asterisk}%
        \item
        \let\theenumi\theenumiBAK
      }%
  }
\newcommand\myitem@asterisk{}
\protected\def\myitem@asterisk{\textsuperscript{*}}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Hihi
  \myitem Haha
  \item Huhu
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Somehow I cannot make it work. I use documentclass{book} and place the relevant part of the code in the main .tex while the chapters are added by \subfile{}. The list is supposed to be in one of the chapters

Comment: @DexzMen do you load any packages changing lists, like e.g. `enumitem`?

Comment: unfortunately yes, I had to add that because equations in the enumerate kept on going out of textwidth

Comment: @PatrickT maybe you want to open a new question with a minimal example showing the problematic behaviour (you could link to this thread there)? Just from this comment I'm not sure what you tried and how your code looks like.

Comment: @Skillmon, Thanks! so it turned out to be a conflict with the beamer class, which I solved by redefining an environment and not using the `enumitem` package at all.

Comment: @PatrickT good to hear you got your things sorted. Yes, `enumitem` is known to be incompatible with `beamer`! Don't ever load the two together.