# Continue numbering within the same enumerate

Tags: numbering, enumerate

I have a long list that I number with `enumerate`.  Some of the items in the list should have a bullet before the numbering. The only way I succeed in doing this is by forcing the numbering of that item as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item item no.1
\item item no.2
\item[$\bullet$(3)] No.3
\item item no.4
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

But of course I would like the item no.4 to be numbered (4) and not (3) again.  How do I do this?

Comment: I've added an answer to [Modifying labels on some enumerated items](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361321/5764) that should address your problem.

Comment: @Werner: Me too ;-)