# Adding symbol before some labels in description

Tags: lists, enumitem, description

I want to do something similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52715/modifying-labels-on-some-enumerated-items), but with a `description` environment.  That is, I want to add an asterisk (or something) before the label text of some of the items in a `description` environment.  As in the accepted answer on that question (among others), I want the labels to be vertically aligned with each other, and the asterisks to appear farther left, which is why I don't just write `\item[*label text]` on the special items.

I'm already using `enumitem` if that's helpful.

Comment: `\newcommand{\lstar}{\llap{*}}` and then `\item[\lstar label text]`.

Comment: @SergeiGolovan That's perfect, thanks.  I'd happily accept that if you made it an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add something with zero length to the label text. One possibility is to define

```
\newcommand{\lstar}{\llap{*}}
```

and then use it

```
\item[\lstar label text] item content
```

If `\llap` seems to be too PlainTeX, you can use

```
\newcommand{\lstar}{\makebox[0pt][r]{*}}
```

instead.